# How to avoid Vuetify overrides default CSS

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

### Summarize the problem

I am trying to implement the Vuetify to a part of an existing project. But after I added Vuetify to the Project. I found out that the "default" CSS styles for like input field, select are changed. And it makes those input field and select all look like plain text rather than input field and select.

Because I only want to implement the Vuetify for a part of the project, so it is bad that the Vuetify overrides the "default" CSS Rules.

I am looking for a way to implement the Vuetify for a part of an existing project. But the rest of the project should be rendered as normal (just with default CSS, not my own CSS).

To make the Qustion more clair, I will put an example which shows two selects. The first one is made with Vuetify `<v-select>` and the second one is made with normal HTML code `<select>`

### Provide background and tell us what you've already tried

I have already tried to put custom CSS rules for input field and select after the Vuetify Script and Vuetify CSS link. But Vuetify still overrides my custom CSS-Styles.

### Show your code

HTML PART:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>Vuetify select:</div>
  <v-select
    :items="items"
  >
  </v-select>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <div>Normal select:</div>
    <select>
      <option value="0">test1</option>
      <option value="1">test2</option>
      <option value="2">test3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS PART:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      items: [
        {
          text: "a"
        },
        {
          text: "b"
        },
        {
          text: "c"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

### Describe expected and actual results

I expected that I can use Vuetify for some parts of this project. But in the meanwhile, the rest of the project should be acting just like normal (with default CSS).

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the Vuetify *reset styles* ([`src/styles/generic/_reset.scss`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/generic/_reset.scss)).

There is also an issue for that problem: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8530. You can find there a [little postcss hack](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8530#issuecomment-594354469) from [mkalus](https://github.com/mkalus) that isolates necessary styles via the wrapper (adding the prefix class to selectors).

In my case I just needed to **remove some element selectors**, excluding those that I added myself. So this is my variation of mkalus's solution with the [postcss-filter-rules](https://github.com/lachlanmcdonald/postcss-filter-rules) plugin.

I used the `filter` option to filter selectors. Its description:

> Selectors are kept if the function returns `true`, otherwise they are removed.

And the `keepAtRules` option to prevent unnecessary deletions:

> By default, `@font-face` and any empty at-rules (after filtering) are removed. To keep specific at-rules, provide an array of names to this option. To keep all at-rules, use the value `true`.

**vue.config.js** (Vue CLI 4):

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const filterRules = require('postcss-filter-rules')

module.exports = {
  /* ... */
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          filterRules({
            filter: (selector) => {
              const re = new RegExp(/^(html|body|\*|ul|ol|select|small)(\W|$)/, 'i')
              const exception  = '.vue-global'
              return !re.test(selector) || selector.includes(exception)
            },
            keepAtRules: true
          }),
          autoprefixer
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Now that I've removed some Vuetify reset styles, I can still style `html` and other elements like this:

```
html.vue-global
  font-size 16px
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a normalize css file to your project and the vuetify styling should only apply to when you want it to, i use [this](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: Can you maybe describe more about how to use it? I am a little confused. If I put this CSS styles before the Vuetify Style, Vuetify will still overrides it right? But If I put this CSS after the Vuetify Style, it will overrides the Vuetify. Which will break my Vuetify UI. How to apply Vuetify styles only to the Vuetify UI is the key. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: adding the normalizer after vuetify won't override the vuetify's custom css for elements, it only touches global html elements and normalizes them, try it

Comment: If that doesn't work a fix would be to import only the components you need, let's say if you need only the `v-select` component you can do so by following this [guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/a-la-carte/)

Comment: That didn't work. I added the normalize.css after the Vuetify. But the Vuetify still make all the input fields and select look like plain text. The import of components which I need won't work either I think. Because say I need the `v-select`, in the other parts of my project I have tons of `<select>`. Vuetify still overrides the CSS-style of select element. I am now thinking the only way maybe to add a class to all my "default" input field, select, button etc. and make them looks like original.

Comment: When you import a component in vuetify it's like adding a class to an element, I recall using vuetify components and still having default styles to my other elements, it's worth giving a shot

Comment: Because I am working on a very old project, which was not built with modules system. So it will be hard to do the conditional import of Vuetify components. But I think I can add a class to my other normal elements. That will work. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Oh i see, but is there any problem in having the vuetify styling? I mean i see no use cases for the default styling of html elements and if you need custom styling that is easy to add

Comment: The problem is, this project only use the default CSS-Style for all the select, input field, button, text area, etc. (You can understand that as no custom CSS, it will be rendered from Browser). And I need to add a new part by using Vuetify. The Vuetify overrides the "default" CSS-styles implemented by the Browser and makes the normal HTML elements all look like plain text. It makes the user hard to find out what is a select and what is a input and what is a button etc.